# Cross validation in R

Tags: validation, r

I have a problem cross validating a dataset in R.

```
mypredict.rpart <- function(object, newdata){
                      predict(object, newdata, type = "class")
                   }
res <- errorest(win~., data=df, model = rpart, predict = mypredict.rpart)
```

I get this error.

> Error in predict.rpart(object, newdata, type = "class") : 
>     Invalid prediction for rpart object

My dataset is made out of 16 numerical atributes and win is has two factor 0 and 1.
You can download the dataset on [link](http://uploading.com/files/3119e8fa/data.Rda/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're doing classification, `win` should be a factor.

```
df$win = factor(df$win)
```

Then your code works for me:

```
> res

Call:
errorest.data.frame(formula = win ~ ., data = df, model = rpart, 
    predict = mypredict.rpart)

     10-fold cross-validation estimator of misclassification error 

Misclassification error:  0.4844
```